# Can you have a Google form pull data from a Google sheet each time a respondent opens it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Hi and thanks for reading. I'm trying to make a system where responders can enter the names of participants in one form. In another form, for entering scores of a competition, responders can select the name in a dropdown menu. I'm not a programmer, but I got quite far by Googling and 'stealing' code. What I have now, is a code in the first form (for adding names). When you submit it, the form adds the name to a Google sheet. Then the code adds the names in the Google sheet to the form for entering scores. So far so good!

But now the problem: there is more than one competition. What I could do, is change the code so that is also adds the names in the Google sheet to the form of the other competition, but that's a lot of work everytime there is a new competition. It would be easier to have a code in the competitionform itself that tells the form: every time someone opens you (as in: a responder, not an editor), run this code. Is that possible? I now use the 'on submit' trigger for the other form, but I actually need an 'on entry' trigger or something like that. I tried 'on open' but that only works when the editor opens the form.

Here is the code I have in the 'add name' form (the trigger is located somewhere else)

```
    function addRider(){
      // call your form and connect to the drop-down item
      var form = FormApp.openById("1NeKicU9d3yqQX1D2ZliE-t87k3OVW8lqn9avhNs54NM");
    
      var riderList = form.getItemById("10469776").asListItem();
    
     // identify the sheet where the data resides needed to populate the drop-down
      var rider = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kLBqtU4ebR3tElrEIZNklmxr0hu5IwE6_UV7AN9T1wE").getSheetByName("Riders");
      
      // grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row
      var riderValues = rider.getRange(2, 3, rider.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
      
      var riderNames = [];
    
      // convert the array ignoring empty cells
      for(var i = 0; i < riderValues.length; i++)   
        if(riderValues[i][0] != "")
          riderNames[i] = riderValues[i][0];
    
      // populate the drop-down with the array data
      riderList.setChoiceValues(riderNames);
    }
```

Comment: `every time someone opens you (as in: a responder, not an editor), run this code. Is that possible?` No, this is not possible. But why this should fire when the form is opened? I understand that the form should be updated with data coming from a spreadsheet, but how is the data added to the spreadsheet? If it is added when submitting a form, maybe you could use that trigger to update the form? I'm not sure I understand the general workflow you have in mind, can you provide more details?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not an experienced programmer, so there is a very good chance my workflow is not the best.

What you suggest is what already happens at the moment: when somebody submits the first form, it adds the data to a spreadsheet (there's no programming needed for that) and the code above takes the data from the spreadsheet, converts it into an array and adds it as possible answers to the second form.

So that works. But what I want to do is copy and paste the second form for another event. But that won't work: the first form only sends the names to the second form.

Comment: I don't think I understand `But what I want to do is copy and paste the second form for another event. But that won't work: the first form only sends the names to the second form.` What exactly you want to send to the second form? And why is it necessary that this runs when the form is opened?

Comment: The first form sends the names that are entered to the second form. In the second form responders can select a name from a namelist. This works. In short:

In first form you enter name. In second form you can choose from the names you entered.

But I want to make more forms; copies from the second form. In these clones, you can't select any names because the names are only sent to the second form. That's why I want to reverse it. In stead of the first form sending the names to the second forms and it's clones, I want the second form and the clones to gather the names themselves.

Comment: Do you have a list of "clones"? In that case, you could have a script to add the names to all these at once. I'm not sure whether this would be appropriate, though, since I'm not sure whether there are requirements about when should this get triggered.

Comment: I see my lack of knowledge is confusing you.  The clones I spoke of are all Google Sheets, so I can't add names to them, they already have them. But I've found a workaround. I'll have the first form send the names to 3 forms. These forms I will use for all events. So the field for the name will always stay the same, but I'll import the other questions for each new event. But better would be if a form can say something like: populate the question in THIS form (without pointing to a particular form) with data from that sheet.

Comment: Now that I think of it, would it be possible to do that with a class? So that I assign these forms to a class that updates itself? Then I could use a webapp to trigger the forms code as soon as it's url is visited?

Comment: Replacing `var form = FormApp.openById(...)` by `var form = FormApp.getActiveForm()` may solve it. Doc: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getactiveform

Comment: Great! I moved the function to the second form and this works! Thanks! Now I'm going to figure out how to make this function run each time someone loads the form. It should be possible with a webapp. Thanks again!

Comment: How are you thinking of running the script when a user visits the form? Would you mind providing more details about the web app you have in mind? I seriously doubt what you want to do is possible.

Comment: @lamblichus Indeed it's impossible to trigger a script when a user visits the form. In the end we went by your idea to maintain a list of clone forms (their ids) in a separate sheet. Each time a user enters a form to add a "rider", its onsubmit trigger loops over the clone ids and sets the new list of riders in these clones. This works pretty well. The cloned form has a script that we have to manually kick off in each new clone, which adds its own id to the sheet with clone ids. Scripts are copied when cloning, but the trigger settings unfortunately are not (hence "manually").

Comment: @AlbertHendriks Can't you have the `onFormSubmit` trigger from the original form be used to make whatever actions are never for each cloned form? As long as you have the corresponding form ids, it should be possible. Maybe I'm missing something or I don't fully understand your situation.

Comment: @lamblichus when cloning (copying) a form, the code for the triggers is copied but the triggers itself are not.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks Triggers can be installed programmatically. You could add the corresponding code to install the trigger for each copy if you are copying the forms via code. Would that be appropriate for you? If that's the case, I'd consider posting an answer explaining this.